# How to use Git within an existing process for web site publishing (like Dreamweaver)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, git, dreamweaver

We are looking at adopting Git for our SCM but having trouble figuring out the best way to integrate it into our processes.

We have backend devs that use VS2010 to edit their solutions but use the built in publishing.

We also have web devs that use tools like Dreamweaver CS5 to edit code for our webtools and publish to our testing and production servers via FTP. Works very well and I don't want to change this process.

However, the way Dreamweaver works is that it mirrors the contents of our web servers down to the local clients. So you make a change and "sync" it with the server and it pushes files there.

If we introduce Git, it will create a code repository that contains website code as well as some visual studio solutions for other work that is deployed to completely different server.

So say this exists:

```
C:\Git-repository\VS2010-Solutions\foo-tool\
C:\Git-repository\VS2010-Solutions\<other solutions>
C:\Git-repository\Web-tools\index.asp
D:\website-root\index.asp
D:\website-root\foo-tool\
```

Our backend devs edit the VS2010-Solution files which will work with Git no problem because VS handles the publishing (so the local file structure is independant of what sits on our servers). However, the web devs will use dreamweaver to edit the index.asp (for example) directly in D:\website-root which are a different instance of the files than in the local git-repository.

(Note the VS publishing puts files into the website-root on the remote servers too, so when Dreamweaver syncs, it pulls down these files too)

What is the right way to approach this and get this all working? My initial thought was to:

1. Eliminate C:\Git-repository\web-tools\
2. Create 2 different Git repositories, one for web-tools and another for the VS solutions
3. Use a .gitignore file in D:\website-root\ to ignore the folders like "\foo-tools" which are already covered in the other git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a .gitgnore file and define which files you want excluded from your git repository.

http://help.github.com/git-ignore/

This way, you can create and manage your DreamWeaver source code repository separately from your (I'm guessing) VSTS repository for the Visual Studio solutions.

Your `.gitignore` file for your DreamWeaver source control will contain the following line

`VS2010-Solutions\*`